# c++ winsock - recv() returns incorrect and strange buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, buffer, winsock, recv

I am writing a simple game named "TicTacToe". I also wanted to create a network function using WinSock. While connection between two users goes without errors, I can't receive any correct data. After receiving it, the buffer is filled with a strange characters like "☺$0/A", etc., while it should receive "Hello!".

Here's my code:

```
const char buf[] = "Hello!";
char rbuf[16];
int bytes = 0;
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

// sending

send(sox, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

// recv

bytes = recv(sox, rbuf, 16, 0)
rbuf[bytes] = '\0';
cout << rbuf << endl;
```

Comment: Always check the return value of recv() for errors.

Comment: please show your real code, this won't compile

Comment: Looks like, you are right, because it always returns SOCKET_ERROR code, thanks for lead! I'll check details later.

Comment: Always check it for EOS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, you're not checking the `return` values of your `send`/`recv` calls, also you can't expect it to always receive 16 bytes. In order to ensure you get what you want to receive, you might have to call `recv` multiple times. Here's an example solution to that problem:

```
int FixedRecv(SOCKET sox, char* rbuf, int length)
{
    int ref, len = 0;
    do {
        ref = recv(sox, rbuf + len, length - len, 0);

        if(ref == 0) return 0;

        if(SOCKET_ERROR != ref)
            len += ref;
        else return SOCKET_ERROR;
    } while(len < length);

    return len;
}
```

Same will also apply to your calls to `send` but I just want you to get a general idea.

Hope that helps, uses a little bit of pointer arithmetic, but nothing
too extensive.

Also, if you're using nonblocking sockets, you will want to check for `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` with `WSAGetLastError`.